# Spacebar in Quicktime Player X used to pause video, no longer does in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, quicktime

It used to be that pressing the space bar in Quicktime Player would pause a video.  However, beginning with Lion, it seems that it sometimes pauses the video, but other times it skips or jumps the video to a random location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is if you use the two fingered gesture to fast-forward or rewind the video.  As soon as you do, you'll notice that the tab focus jumps to the position indicator.

Here's a normal Quicktime Player control before using gestures:
[image]

Here's what the control looks like as soon as you use a fast-forward or rewind gesture:
[image]

Notice that the diamond position indicator is now blue.

Seems to be a particularly annoying bug in the player.

Comment: If anyone is filing a bug report, it only seems to happen when full keyboard access is enabled.